# how to manualy add logging handler to gunicorn logger in standalone application?

Tags: python, logging, logstash, gunicorn

I am write standalone gunicorn application like this: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html?highlight=standalone

And I want to logging gunicorn error messages in logstash. 
My question:

How to get gunicorn error (and access) logger objects inside my app and add handler on it?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use my logger so this response is about replacing logger (to my own configured in my own method). If you only want to add handler then you can add handlers to `access_log` and `error_log`. I needed to change logger and I've done it in that way:

```
from gunicorn.glogging import Logger as GLogger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class GunicornLogger(GLogger):
    def setup(self, cfg):
        super(GunicornLogger, self).setup(cfg)
        self.access_log = logger
        self.error_log = logger
```

and while starting up application:

```
self.options['logger_class'] = '<import_to_this_file>.GunicornLogger'
```

Note: after that `accesslog` and `errorlog` config params will have no effect because I've overwritten original loggers. As I said you can just register new handlers if you want...

works for me with `gunicorn==19.7.1`